# Converting C array and pointer code to Go

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, go

I'm trying to rewrite a C code in Go, and what I notice is that the code that I try to rewrite follows a lot one common pattern. Many of the functions accept `unsigned char` arrays, passed as pointer, and either when calling the functions or at some other part of the function we add some value to the `char` pointer, as doing arithmetic. Here is a simple example just for demonstration purposes.

```
static void func1(unsigned char *r) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < CONSTANT; i++)
        func2(r + i * OTHER_CONSTANT);
}

static void func2(const unsigned char *a) {
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < CONSTANT; i += 8) {
        // do some stuff
        a += 3;
    }
}
```

What is a proper way to convert something like this to Go? I started to use `byte` slices in order to represent the `char` arrays, but I don't know how to exactly transfer those arithmetic expression with `char` into arithmetic with ranges/indexes in Go. I ended up having something like this:

```
func func1(r []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < CONSTANT; i++ {
        func2(r + i*OTHER_CONSTANT) // This just doesn't work
    }
}
func func2(a []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < CONSTANT; i += 8 {
        // do some stuff
        a += 3 // This doesn't work
    }
}
```

Any idea how to convert something like above from C to Go?

Comment: You have to use indexes in the array instead of pointers. What you get with this is boundary check of indexed access. This makes your Go program safer than the C code, though bit slower too. You may also use slices, which can make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be slicing `r` and `a`, which you can do in the following way:

```
func func1(r []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < CONSTANT; i++ {
        func2(r[i*OTHER_CONSTANT:])
    }
}
func func2(a []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < CONSTANT; i += 8 {
        // do some stuff
        a = a[3:]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go does not have pointer arithmetic:

https://golang.org/doc/faq#no_pointer_arithmetic

So you should just work with indexes that point to positions on the array, and slices to get parts of the array:

```
func func1(r []byte) {
    rIndex := 0
    for i := 0; i < CONSTANT; i++ {
        func2(r[rIndex + i*OTHER_CONSTANT:])
    }
}
```

And:

```
func func2(a []byte) {
    aIndex := 0
    for i := 0; i < CONSTANT; i += 8 {
        // do some stuff
        aIndex += 3
        // use a[aIndex] when needed
    }
}
```